# Concatenating various dfs with different columns but removing repeats

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been web-scraping a website that has information on many chemical compounds. The problem is that despite all the pages having some information that is the same, it's not consistent. So that means I'll have different amount of columns with each extraction. I want to organize everything in an Excel file so that it's easier for me to filter the information that I want but I've been having a lot of trouble with it.

Examples (there's way more than only 3 dataframes being extracted though):
DF 1 - From web-scraping the first page

| Compound Name | Study Type | Cas Number | EC Name | Remarks | Conclusions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aspirin | Specific | 3439-73-9 | Aspirin | Repeat | Approved |

DF 2 - From web-scraping

| Compound Name | Study Type | Cas Number | EC Name | Remarks | Conclusions | Summary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EGFR | Specific | 738-9-8 | EGFR | Repeat | Not Approved | None Conclusive |

DF 3 - From web-scraping

| Compound Name | Study Type | Cas Number | Remarks | Conclusions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Benzaldehyde | Specific | 384-92-2 | Repeat | Not Approved |

What I want is something like this:

FINAL DF (image)
[image: 1]

I've tried so many things with pd.concat but all attempts were unsucessful.

The closest I've gotten was something similar to this, repeating the columns:

| Compound Name | Study Type | Cas Number | EC Name | Remarks | Conclusions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aspirin | Specific | 3439-73-9 | Aspirin | Repeat | Approved |
| Compound Name | Study Type | Cas Number | Remarks | Conclusions |  |
| Benzaldehyde | Specific | 384-92-2 | Repeat | Not Approved |  |
| Compound Name | Study Type | Cas Number | EC Name | Remarks | Conclusions |
| EGFR | Specific | 738-9-8 | EGFR | Repeat | Not Approved |

Here's a little bit of the current code I'm trying to write:

```
compound_info = []
descriptor_info = []
df_list = []
df = pd.DataFrame()
df_final = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Compound Name',
                                'Study Type',
                                'CAS Number',
                                'EC Name',
                                'Remarks',
                                'Conclusions'])

for i in range(1,num_btn_selecionar+1):
   time.sleep(10)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SectionHeader"]/div[3]/select/option[' + str(i) +']').click()
   page_source = driver.page_source
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
   info = soup.find_all("dl", {'class':'HorDL'})
   lista_info = len(info)
   all_info_compound = []
   all_descrip_compound = []
   for y in range(0, lista_info):
       for z in info[y].find_all('dd'):
           all_info_compound.append(z.text)
       for w in info[y].find_all('dt'):
           all_descrip_compound.append(w.text)
   compound_info.append(all_info_compound)
   descriptor_info.append(all_descrip_compound)
   
   data_tuples = list(zip(all_descrip_compound[1:],all_info_compound[1:]))
   temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data_tuples)
   data_transposed = temp_df.T
   #df_list.append(data_transposed)
   pd.concat([df_final,data_transposed], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
```

The error I get is:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I would highly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.concat` should do the job. The reason for that error is that one of the dataframes in `concat`, which is very likely to be `data_transposed`, has two columns sharing the same name. To see this, you can replace your last line with

```
try:
    df_final = pd.concat([df_final,data_transposed], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
except Exception as e:
    print('Error:', e)
    print('df_final:', df_final.columns)
    print('data_transposed:', data_transposed.columns)
```

Also in your last line you never overwrite your `df_final` with the new, concatenated one, you need `df_final =`  in the front as I have added to my code above.

Comment: Yay! Thanks, your solution really helped me out, it had to do with me not specifying that the first row were the columns and the fact that there really were columns sharing the same name because the page would have these repetitions anyways when I web-scraped them.